# Laravel Eloquent - consider parent's deleted_at

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models:

```
User:
  id
  parent_id (belongsTo)
  deleted_at

Parent:
  id
  deleted_at
```

I am using Laravel's [SoftDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#soft-deleting) trait. Currently it filters out `users` or `parents` when queried individually (rows with `deleted_at` null only).

But I want to filter out `user` not only when `deleted_at` not null, but also when it's `parent`'s `deleted_at` not null too.

How can I apply global scope to my model, so that it will consider it's parent's `deleted_at` too?

Comment: `User::has("parent")->where(...)` should work

Comment: @apokryfos I knew there was something like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any of the methods to [query existing relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), and I would personally use the `whereHas()` method which offers more flexibility:

```
User::whereHas('parent', function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('deletedAt', '>', 'somedate');
    });
```

That way you could apply even more condition to the relationship.